# Objective-C application's kAEGetURL event handler is not called after starting second thread

Tags: java, objective-c, java-native-interface

I have a Cocoa app that runs Java Virtual Machine in separate thread (through JNI). The app registers event handler to handle URL protocol `myprotocol://`. Registration is implemented like this:

```
NSAppleEventManager *appleEventManager = [NSAppleEventManager sharedAppleEventManager];

[appleEventManager setEventHandler:self andSelector:@selector(handleGetURLEvent:withReplyEvent:) forEventClass:kInternetEventClass andEventID:kAEGetURL];
```

`handleGetURLEvent` is my handler method.

The handler gets called if I don't start the JVM thread. The handler doesn't get called if I start the JVM thread and the Java app running in JVM gets to the point where it initializes AWT GUI. any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I have solved it. Java installs itself as the target for AppleEvents after it loads Swing/AWT. Don't know why. It just replaced my event handler. I just set my event handler again (replace Java's one) after Java sets it. I use this code to set event handler:

```
NSAppleEventManager *appleEventManager = [NSAppleEventManager sharedAppleEventManager];

[appleEventManager setEventHandler:self andSelector:@selector(handleGetURLEvent:withReplyEvent:) forEventClass:kInternetEventClass andEventID:kAEGetURL];
```